# How to run a Java Applet on Mac OS 10.6.6

Tags: java, html, macos, safari, applet

I am in my first programming class and I am now reaching the end of the semester.  I have an online portfolio where I share my college accomplishments.  At this point in the semester, I would like to upload some of the simple Applets I have created to my online portfolio.  My portfolio is hosted on Weebly.com.  I tried uploading the files to the host site and using the simple  tags to run the applet within the html.  I'm quite sure I'm accessing the files using the correct directories.  But before we jump to any conclusions there, I decided I ought to run the applets locally to ensure I'm doing everything correctly.  I am on a macbook pro running OS 10.6.6. In Java Preferences, my Java SE versions are Java SE 6 64-bit and Java SE 6 32-bit.  My plug-in version is 1.6.0 (found in /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines).  These are the only versions I have on my machine.  My research tells me that I may be having version disagreements.  Some forums have suggested going back to plug-in version 1.5 (although, I have no idea how). I'm pretty sure now though that apple has updated Safari to a 64-bit version.  I have Eclipse set to 1.6 also.  Everything seems to be on the same page to me.

And yes, I've read all the related questions on here over and over.  Most of them are a little outdated now.

Here's my applet code:

```
/** 
 * Class NightScene - Draws a night scene (just for fun). 
 *  
 * @author Alex Stout 
 * @version February 8, 2011 
 */ 
package lab05_1; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class NightScene extends JApplet 
{ 
        /** 
         * Paint method for applet. 
         *  
         * @param  g   the Graphics object for this applet 
         */ 
        public void paint(Graphics g) 
        { 
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE.darker().darker().darker());
            g.fillRect(0,0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

            this.drawMoon(g);

            this.drawStars(g);

            this.drawHorizon(g);

        }
        public void drawStars(Graphics h)
        {   
            for (int i = 0 ; i <= this.getWidth()*5; i++)
            {
                int x = (int)(Math.random()*this.getWidth());
                int y = (int)(Math.random()*this.getHeight());

                h.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                h.fillOval (x, y, (int) (Math.random()*3)+1, (int) (Math.random()*3)+1);
            }

        }
        public void drawMoon(Graphics j)
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random()*(this.getWidth()-200)+50);
            int y = (int)(Math.random()*(this.getHeight()-200)+50);

            j.setColor(Color.YELLOW.brighter().brighter());
            j.fillOval (x, y, this.getWidth()/10, this.getWidth()/10);
            j.setColor (Color.BLUE.darker().darker().darker());
            j.fillOval (x-(this.getWidth()/100), y-(this.getWidth()/100), this.getWidth()/10, this.getWidth()/10);
        }   

        public void drawHorizon(Graphics k)
        {
            int xi = 0;
            int xj = this.getWidth();
            int yj = this.getHeight();
            int rh = this.getHeight()-this.getHeight()/8;

            for (int i=0; i < xj; i++)
            {
                k.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                k.drawLine(xi, yj, xi, rh);

                k.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                if(Math.random()<0.50)
                {
                    k.drawLine(xi++, rh++, xi, rh++);
                }
                else
                {
                    k.drawLine(xi++, rh--, xi, rh--);
                }

            }           
        }
}
```

Here's my html code:

```
<html>
<Applet code = NightScene.class codebase = "." width = "400" height = "400">
</Applet>
</html>
```

Here's the Java Console output:

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_24
Using JRE version 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = /Users/myUserName
```

Some people have suggested using codebase = "." so I tried that to no avail.  It doesn't work with or without it.  I tried putting in the full directory path, no success.  I tried quotes and no quotes around the class name.  I tried with and without .class on the end.  I tried making a lab05_1 subdirectory because that's the package name in the code.  No luck.  Both the class file and the html file are in the same folder on the desktop.  The class file is a copy of the original one that was created in Eclipse, but it has the same name, so I wouldn't think this should cause any problems being in different directories.

I don't know what else to do. Please Help! This has been irking me for a week. I've spent hours upon hours on something so simple.

Comment: I've had the most luck running java applets using Firefox, for what is worth.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it does run in the applet viewer when I run it in Eclipse. It's just when I try to run them in a browser (Safari or Firefox) that they don't work.

Comment: @CarlosZ Thanks CarlosZ, I have been trying firefox as well, to no avail. :/

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I'm getting a little more life out of the applet tests now.  It shows the java load image then notifies me that it can't be loaded and that there was an error.  The console returns a much more lively error now. It's a NoClassFound Exception. Then it seems like it wants my package name or something.
`Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: NightScene (wrong name: lab05_1/NightScene)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Mac handy to check this, but if you change your HTML file, it should work --- you are missing the package name for the NightScene.class.

```
<html>
  <Applet code="lab05_1.NightScene.class" width="400" height="400"/>
</html>
```

The Oracle reference for the APPLET tag is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet.html).

From that page:

> **CODE** = ***appletFile***
>
> This REQUIRED
>   attribute gives the name of the file
>   that contains the applet's compiled
>   Applet subclass. This file is relative
>   to the base URL of the applet. It
>   cannot be absolute. One of CODE or
>   OBJECT must be present. The value
>   *appletFile* can be of the form
>   *classname.class* or of the form
>   ***packagename.classname.class***.

---

*EDIT:* Just in case it's not clear, the directory should be laid out like so:

```
    +-top-level/
      |
      +-lab05_1/
      | |
      | +-NightScene.class
      |
      +-test.html
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I got it working with that code! It also works with forward slashes.  Okay, now that I've gotten that working. I just need to get it working on my host site.  The problem there is that they require you to upload all your files into a one-level directory. So I can't put the class file into a subdirectory. Am I supposed to alter my class file so the package name matches the directory from weebly? Any ideas there?  Thanks again, Spong, you rock!

Comment: I think that if you are not able to create the `lab05_1` sub-directory, then you will need to remove the package declaration from your java source file and recompile.  You will also need to remove the package name from the html as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe old now, I just found this page in trying to answer a different question, but for what it's worth, looking at your original HTML and the ORacle link, I see you did not have quotation marks around the class file name. Suspect that may really have been the root of problem. In effect this is perhaps what 'Spong' is getting at too. I just didn't see any mention of the quotation marks which is what jumped out at me...